# handling exception in express and avoid server restart

Tags: node.js, express

i am building a site which as transactions using expressjs and i am using forever to keep my server up and running .

imagine there are two persons person A and person B

person A is performing some transactions to buy credits

person B's exception somehow causes the an exception which is equal to server crash and restart

My question is 
1)what will happen to person A's transaction
2)how can avoid server crash from any kind of uncaught exception
3)is there any way to save the current state of server when the server crashes

Answer (score 1):

if you are using mongodb

1)what will happen to person A's transaction 
it totally depends on kind of exception handling you have done moreover you may add rollback fuctionality for nosql db 
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

2)how can avoid server crash from any kind of uncaught exception

try this url and always try domains dont swallow exceptions this is wrong for more help try this blog http://shapeshed.com/uncaught-exceptions-in-node/

3)is there any way to save the current state of server when the server crashes

use forever pm2 and logging option where the server crashed

Comment: i am using mysl since mongodb doesnt support transactions and rollback might not run as server crashed

Comment: Great,then i would suggest use                                process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
})                                                                                                              this is a bad way and we should normally not use but in your case its a solution